# Contracted ideals in number fields

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to translate a section of Wolfgang Krull's report "Idealtheorie". At one point (Section $7$ on Quotient Rings) I believe that he makes something like the following statement:

Suppose for example that $K$ and $L$ are finite algebraic number fields with $K$ contained in $L$ and let $R$ resp. $S$ be the ring of all integers in $K$ resp. $L$. Then the set of all contracted ideals in $R$ consists of all ideals of $R$.

My question is "Have I got this right (my German is not great). i.e. is this true of rings of integers?" Clearly it is not true in general.

Comment: Could you give the statement in German ?

Comment: NB Previously: 
Bezeichnet man mit $\Lambda_r$ die Menge der Verengungsideale aller $\mathfrak{c}_s$ in \textfrak{R}.


Then:

Sind z.B. \textfrak{K} und \textfrak{L}$\supset$\textfrak{K} endliche algebraische Zahlk\"orper und bedeutet \textfrak{R} bzw. \textfrak{S} den Ring aller ganzen Zahlen aus \textfrak{K} bzw. \textfrak{L}, so besteht zun\"achst $\Lambda_r$ aus allen Idealen von \textfrak{R}, es enth\"alt also $\Lambda_r$ mit $\mathfrak{a}$ und $\mathfrak{b}$ stets auch $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{a\cdot\mathfrak{b}}$.

Comment: NB Previously we have defined: 
Bezeichnet man mit $\Lambda_r$ die Menge der Verengungsideale aller $\mathfrak{c}_s$ in R.


Then the text in question is:

Sind z.B. K und L $\supset$ K endliche algebraische Zahlkorper und bedeutet R bzw. S den Ring aller ganzen Zahlen aus K bzw. L, so besteht zunachst $\Lambda_r$ aus allen Idealen von R, es enthalt also $\Lambda_r$ mit $\mathfrak{a}$ und $\mathfrak{b}$ stets auch $\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{a\cdot\mathfrak{b}}$.(Sorry don't know how to do umlauts in comment!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if your translation is correct, but your statement about ideals is correct: the ring extension $R\subseteq S$ is flat, because for every prime ideal $q$ of $S$ the localization $S_q$ is a flat $R_p$-module, $p:=q\cap A$, since $R_p$ is a discrete valuation domain and $S_q$ is torsion-free. Moreover the natural map $\mathrm{Spec}(S)\rightarrow\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is surjective, hence $R\subseteq S$ is faithfully flat.

A faithfully flat ring extensions $R\subseteq S$ has the property $IS\cap R=I$ for every ideal $I$ of $R$.

Comment: OK I will go away and try and particularise this to rings of integers. Good to know the translation was probably OK